# Uploading video to google drive using MAUI .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui, maui-community-toolkit

`namespace MauiApplast
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
private static readonly string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the camera and capture a video
        var video = await MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
        {
            Title = "Capture a video"
        });
        if (video != null)
        {
            using (var stream = await video.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                // Convert the video stream to a byte array
                byte[] videoData = await ConvertStreamToByteArray(stream);

                // Authenticate and create the DriveService
                var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "587423489878-q2lu20b0ft2ape7uuhl76s74bka6k0o8.apps.googleusercontent.com", ClientSecret = "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" },
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store"));

                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "MauiApp"
                });

                // Create the file metadata
                var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
                {
                    Name = "MyVideo.mp4" // Set the desired file name
                };

                // Create the upload stream
                using (var uploadStream = new MemoryStream(videoData))
                {
                    // Upload the file
                    var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, uploadStream, "video/mp4");
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    var uploadProgress = await request.UploadAsync();

                    if (uploadProgress.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully!");
                        Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + request.ResponseBody.Id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("File upload failed.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static async Task<byte[]> ConvertStreamToByteArray(Stream stream)
    {
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    } 
}
```

}`

I want to upload captured video to google drive using Maui but got this error while running on android

'Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=587423489878-q2lu20b0ft2ape7uuhl76s74bka6k0o8.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A46506%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization; platform not supported.